# scale fill gradient with fixed limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to fill a county's color on a map depending on the value of Variable X. X is a percentage value with a theoretical range from 0 (0%) and 1 (100%).

However, when I plot my data, the filling color for a given value depends on the actual range present in my data. For example, the value 50% is orange when `max(VARIABLE.X)` = 1 but not orange for a dataset where `max(VARIABLE.X)` = 0.5.

How do I get R to assign the same color to each value across different data sets?

This is the code I use:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=VARIABLE.X)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn (colours = heat.colors(10))
```

Comment: Try `scale_fill_gradientn (colours = heat.colors(10), limits = c(0, 1))`.